# What is an A-19 light bulb or lamp?

Tags: bulb, lamp, motion-sensor

This may sound simple to some but I bought a couple exterior light fixtures.  They say only use type A-19 light bulbs or lamps.  From what I guessed looking through the net I think this means no CFL energy saving bulbs.  What exactly is an A-19 type light bulb?  The light fixtures I bought have a sensor and dual-brite dimmable lighting capability which I don't even plan on using.  I want it on at 100% brightness at all times.

Answer (score 1):

It defines the physical size of bulb that can be accomodated.

> The most commonly used A-series light bulb type is the A19 bulb, which is 2 3⁄8 inches (60 mm) wide at its widest point, approximately 4 3⁄8 inches (110 mm) in length, and has a one-inch wide (type E26, i.e. approximately 26 millimetres wide) Edison screw base.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-series_light_bulb)

Any CFL that fits in the space provided should work

Some LED lamps sometimes need airflow to keep their temperature in operating ranges. So might have issues in a fully enclosed fixture

Answer (score 0):

A-19 is simply an odd way of saying "use standard light bulbs here".  Check the documentation that came with your fixtures to see if dimmable CFL/LED types are acceptable (they should be in this day and age, but may have performance restrictions).